# how to count number of td/tr in a table with Robot Framework using Selenium2Library

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to automatically check the number of TDs or TRs in a table.

I am using Get Matching XPath Count keyword from Selenium, however, it always fails with an error.

My sample HTML structure:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
      <td style="width: 50%">my td</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
      <td>Search me</td>
      <td>Pagination here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using the keyword with XPath : .//[@id='myTable']/tr/td/@width

Because I just want to count td with a "width" attribute.

and the error: InvalidSelectorException: Message: u"invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression...

Any solution?
thanks

Comment: In your case, `width` is the **value** of the attribute `style`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this XPath to get `<td>` having `style` attribute value contains `width` :

```
.//table[@id='myTable']/tr/td[contains(@style, 'width')]
```

Comment: Thank you. I can use it with keyword Get Matching Xpath Count now. It works.